# How can I get rid of the call to action button on my Weebly site?

Tags: weebly

I can't find any way to get rid of the call to action button on my landing page layout in Weebly. Is it possible to get rid of this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform two steps.

1. Remove the button from the desktop layout.

   - Open the layout file in HTML edit mode.
   - Remove the following line:

     ```
     <div class="button-wrap">{action:button global="false"}</div>
     ```
2. Remove the button from the mobile layout.

   - Add the following script to the Header Code of the page:

     ```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
     <script language='javascript'>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.landing-container').remove();
         });
     </script>
     ```

You can see it in action on this site for [gluten free products](http://www.rensiesespensie.co.za).